# How to find the Base64 image width and height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I find the Base64 image width and height?

```html
<img id="thumb0" width="200" height="200"
src="data:image/png;base64, ................">
```

The image properties *width* and *height* are constant as I need to show them as a thumbnail, but whereas the original image properties are different.

I need to get the original image height and width.

Suppose my original image height and width are 750 X 500 pixels.

I tried like this, but I am getting the property width and height:

```javascript
$("#thumb0").width();
```

The value is **200**.

How can I get the original width and height of the image?

Comment: Images (on Firefox at least) have a naturalWidth/height property so you can use img.naturalWidth to get the original width

Comment: tried in firebug in firefox it is saying undefined

Comment: Its working for me in both Firefox and Chrome.. Note that the image must be completely loaded to use naturalWidth / naturalHeight properties..

Comment: @SaiPrasad +1 This is a good idea but I can't find information regarding compatibility of this property which was, I think, only normalized in HTML5. If you can find it, this should be an answer.

Comment: You can find answer in another question, here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17774928/js-get-image-width-and-height-from-the-base64-code

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can build another image element and get its size:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = $('#thumb0').attr('src');
var originalWidth = img.width;
```

Comment: But i think it will take to time for huge images and we need to destroy after creating?

Comment: No, it will be very fast, especially as there is no request to issue. And you have no destruction to do : as soon as you leave the function where img is declared, it's cleaned.

Comment: @dystroy It does not work in android ~~~, any way to make it works ?

Answer (score 14):

The [Image() constructor for HTMLImageElements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) mentioned in [Denys Séguret's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274822/how-to-find-the-base64-image-width-and-height/14274843#14274843) is the right way to go, but there's a caveat: The constructor is actually asynchronous! As a result, you may experience unexpected behavior in certain browsers; from my limited experiments, Denys Séguret's code will work 100% of the time in Chrome, but only sometimes in Firefox and Safari. Don't know about others.

The right way to do it seems to be [with an onload handler](http://support.spinetix.com/wiki/HTMLImageElement), as in:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = some_base64_image_source;
console.log(img.width);       // This might print out 0!
img.onload = function() {
    console.log(img.width);   // This will print out the width.
}
```