# Get image width and height from the Base64 code in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, base64, dimensions

I have a Base64 image encoded that you can find [here](https://soo.gd/nmpe). How can I get the height and the width of it?

Comment: Link rot has set in for this question

Comment: Yep. *"Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site. We can’t connect to the server at soo.gd."*

Answer (score 189, accepted):

```
var i = new Image();

i.onload = function(){
  alert(i.width + ", " + i.height);
};

i.src = imageData;
```

Comment: too bad that this is an asynchronous process.

Comment: @CoenDamen yep. I need synchronous process as well.

Comment: I would also add that the order here is very important. If you do this the other way around (src before onload) you may miss the event. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2342181/4826740

Comment: @CoenDamen why should the whole script block just to get information on the image size?

Comment: can't we do it without loading the image from the string ?

Comment: string or url, the image has to be loaded for client to get the dimension. do you have something else in mind?

Comment: `imageData` should be in the format `data:image/png;base64,` then the base 64 image data.

Comment: To get width and height synchronously inside an asyc function you can use `decode()` as described in one of the other answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71804221

Answer (score 54):

For synchronous use just wrap it into a promise like this:

```
function getImageDimensions(file) {
  return new Promise (function (resolved, rejected) {
    var i = new Image()
    i.onload = function(){
      resolved({w: i.width, h: i.height})
    };
    i.src = file
  })
}
```

then you can use await to get the data in synchronous coding style:

```
var dimensions = await getImageDimensions(file)
```

Comment: It's still asynchronous though. Just using syntactic sugar.

Comment: 'naturalWidth' and 'naturalHeight` are the better choices no? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28167137/whats-the-difference-between-width-naturalwidth-and-clientwidth

Answer (score 26):

I found that using `.naturalWidth` and `.naturalHeight` had the best results.

```js
const img = new Image();

img.src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150';

img.onload = function() {
  const imgWidth = img.naturalWidth;
  const imgHeight = img.naturalHeight;

  console.log('imgWidth: ', imgWidth);
  console.log('imgHeight: ', imgHeight);
};
```

Documentation:

- *[HTMLImageElement.naturalWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/naturalWidth)*
- *[HTMLImageElement.naturalHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/naturalHeight)*

This is only supported in modern browsers. *[NaturalWidth and NaturalHeight in IE](http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/naturalwidth-and-naturalheight-in-ie/)*

Comment: Exactly, it is the original size of image before being resized by ```object-fit```

Answer (score 12):

A more modern solution is to use [`HTMLImageElement.decode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/decode) instead of the `onload` event. `decode()` returns a promise and thus can be used synchronously with `await`.

Asynchronous use:

```js
let img = new Image();
img.src = "myImage.png";
img.decode().then(() => {
    let width = img.width;
    let height = img.height;
    // Do something with dimensions
});
```

Synchronous use (inside an async function):

```js
let img = new Image();
img.src = "myImage.png";
await img.decode();
let width = img.width;
let height = img.height;
// Do something with dimensions
```

Comment: Awesome answer, learned something new today.

Answer (score 1):

Create a hidden `<img>` with that image and then use jQuery's .width() and . height()

```
$("body").append("<img id='hiddenImage' src='" + imageData + "' />");
var width = $('#hiddenImage').width();
var height = $('#hiddenImage').height();
$('#hiddenImage').remove();
alert("width:" + width + " height:" + height);
```

Test here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pZ4y8/)

The image is not initially created hidden. It gets created, and then you get width and height and then remove it. This may cause a very short visibility in large images. In this case, you have to wrap the image in another container and make that container hidden, not the image itself.

---

Another Fiddle that does not add to the DOM as per [gp.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17774928/get-image-width-and-height-from-the-base64-code-in-javascript/17775293#17775293):
[**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/pZ4y8/2/)

Comment: var i = new Image();
i.src = imageData;
setTimeout(function(){
alert ( "width:"+ i.width+" height:" + i.height );
},100);

Comment: this is only a fix needed because of the nature of the jsfiddle, you can change onLoad to onDomReady instead to fix that initial 0 width and height problem. Code assumes you call this function somewhere in your work where document is already loaded.

Comment: Guess your point being was, that you do not need to add anything to dom to get width and height. Will modify answer to reflect your suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

```
const img = new Image();
img.src = dataUrl;
await img.decode();
const width, height =  img.width, img.height;
```