# Get width and height of an image loaded via a FileReader

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image that is created via a `FileReader`:

```
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    fileReader.onload = function(event) {
        deferred.resolve(event.target.result);
    };

    fileReader.onerror = function() {
        deferred.reject(this);
    };

    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);

    return deferred.promise();
```

This returns a base64 encoded string which I use with:

```
var img = $('<img src="' + fileB64 + '">');
```

Then this is added to my page.

I wish to get the original height and width of that image.

I can get the size of it on the page via:

```
this.img = img;
this.imgWidth = this.img.width();
this.imgHeight = this.img.height();
```

But I wish to get its original width and height.

Comment: You can add an `onload` event to your image and check in the callback what the height and width is.

Comment: This is not a duplicate - I'm asking the the images original width and height.

Comment: @user3729576 It *is* a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17774928/js-get-image-width-and-height-from-the-base64-code).

Comment: @Jack no it isn't. i want the original width of a query object,

Comment: Original width of a query object? What does that even mean? Could you give a clearer example of what you need?

Answer (score 2):

I think the only way you can determine the image's width and height is to actually create an image element and then get the dimensions from that:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = fileB64;
var width = img.width;
var height = img.height;
```

I'm assuming (i.e. I haven't checked) that loading a `data:` URL into an image's `src` property will cause it to load synchronously.  Use `img.onload` otherwise.

Having created the element off-screen like this, you can then add the very same element into the page.

Comment: How would I then add the image to the page? I need to get the dimensions later on in another class once it's been added to the page.

Comment: Just use your normal jQuery stuff, e.g. `$(document.body).append(img)`

Comment: But then how do you get the images original width and height?

Comment: if it's already in the page, just read the element's `width` and `height` properties, or are you somehow modifying the element's size before inserting it?  If so, the question as asked is a complete red herring.  On modern browsers you may be able to use the `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` properties, though.