# How to check image width and height before upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

for picture upload i wrote following html code :

```
<input type="file" id="upload" class="im" onchange="fileSelectHandlerProfile('defaultProfile','true')" style="cursor:pointer"/>
```

when we done with select image,

this code will be fired :

```
function fileSelectHandlerProfile(title, defalutProfile) {
    var oFile;
    oFile = $('#thumbUploadProfile')[0].files[0];
    var rFilter = /^(image\/jpeg|image\/png|image\/gif|image\/bmp|image\/jpg|image\/pjpeg)$/i;
    if (!rFilter.test(oFile.type)) {
        $('.errorProfile').html('Please select a valid image file (jpg and png are allowed)').show();
    }
}
```

i want to check the oFile width and height, how can it is possible like oFile.type?

Comment: As Merlin answered you can validate and also integrate it with JQuery form validations try this http://sgeek.org/validate-image-dimension-using-jquery/

Answer (score 5):

A solutions is to load it clienside and check the height and width.

```
function fileSelectHandlerProfile(title, defalutProfile) {
var oFile;
oFile = $('#thumbUploadProfile')[0].files[0];
var rFilter = /^(image\/jpeg|image\/png|image\/gif|image\/bmp|image\/jpg|image\/pjpeg)$/i;
if (!rFilter.test(oFile.type)) {
    $('.errorProfile').html('Please select a valid image file (jpg and png are allowed)').show();
}

var picReader = new FileReader();

picReader.addEventListener("load", function (event) {

    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.src = event.target.result;
    imageObj.onload = function () {
        //TEST IMAGE SIZE
        if (imageObj.height < 100 || imageObj.width < 100) {
            $('.errorProfile').html('Please select an image with correct dimensions').show();
        }
    };
});

//Read the image
picReader.readAsDataURL(oFile);
```

}

Comment: one of best solutions in 2019

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in 2 steps:

1. Read the image file content as data url using html5 file api:

```js
var reader  = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function () {
    //var dataUrl = reader.result;
    //code as per step 2 here...
}
reader.readAsDataURL(oFile);

//ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader.readAsDataURL
```

2. Now read the image size by creating `Image` object with the dataUrl as src.

   Details: [JS - get image width and height from the base64 code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17774928/js-get-image-width-and-height-from-the-base64-code/17775293#17775293)

Answer (score 2):

```
    var width;
    var height;
    var oFile;
    oFile = $('#thumbUploadProfile')[0].files[0];

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e){
        var image = new Image();
        image.onload  = function(){            
            width = img.width;
            height = img.height;
        }
        image.src   = e.target.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(oFile);
```

Answer (score 1):

The [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) allows you to use `FileReader.readAsDataURL` to read the file as a `data:` url. Use that url as the `src` attribute of a `<img />` tag and read the `width` and `height` attribute of that image.