# how to get image height and width resolution in angularJS/Javascript before uploading

Tags: angularjs

I'm uploading Image ,before uploading I need to check the image resolution whether it is greater than 920*675 resolution,should not allow images to upload less than the resolution(920*675)

Comment: AngularJS or Angular (V2/4+)?

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to know the size before uploading. You can always set it to null if it's not valid, but after an upload. Unless you are talking about uploading to a server after selecting it

Comment: @Lissy -Angular JS

Comment: @AlekseySolovey ,once you choose image to upload and submit to upload just before uploading to server am able to get the file size but not it's height and widht resolutions.

Comment: Potentially: `var img = new Image();`, `img.src = your_image;` with `img.width` and `img.height` for your resolutions

Comment: +1  @AlekseySolovey - he is correct you don't need to upload to a server, you can do this all client-side

Answer (score 0):

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = onLoadFile;
reader.readAsDataURL(filtItem._file);
          
function onLoadFile(event) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = event.target.result;
    console.log(img.width, img.height)
}
```

This is the code snippet copied from https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/blob/master/examples/image-preview/directives.js.

This is now part of the [HTML5 File API](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/), so in short you can use:

```
const i = new Image(); 
i.onload = () => console.log( i.width+", "+i.height );
i.src = imageData;
```

See also:

- [Get file size before uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497404/get-file-size-before-uploading)
- [How to check image width and height before upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26428765/how-to-check-image-width-and-height-before-upload)