# What's the difference between width, naturalWidth, and clientWidth?

Tags: dom

What is the difference between `width`, `naturalWidth`, and `clientWidth`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with JavaScript. It's a question about DOM properties.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Read this:

[Understanding offsetWidth, clientWidth, scrollWidth and -Height, respectively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21064101/understanding-offsetwidth-clientwidth-scrollwidth-and-height-respectively)

**example: `<img>` tag**

`naturalWidth`: it is the original width of the image used in  tag.

`width`: it is the value/default value of width attribute of  tag.

Comment: is there any way to get original width of image before loading the image?

Comment: use Load event of image and get the width & height or you can use:

**var w = document.querySelector('img').naturalWidth;**

Comment: You didnt explain clientWidth

Answer (score 3):

`clientWidth` represents the width of the element and is subject to manipulation by the browser. For example, a 300px wide image can be resized and this manipulated value will come through in `clientWidth`.

`naturalWidth` is the natural width of the element. In the example of a 300px wide image, the `naturalWidth` will still be 300 even if the image is resized in the browser via CSS or JavaScript.