# I'm trying to get the height of the image from base64

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the height of the image from base64. Here's my code,

```
let reader = new FileReader()
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
reader.onloadend = function() {
    let img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = reader.result; //data:image/png;base64,...
    console.log(img.height);
}
```

and looking on log it return 0.

How to get the height of the image in that way?

Full code

```
function handleDrop(e) {
    var dt = e.dataTransfer
    var files = dt.files

    handleFiles(files)
}

function handleFiles(files) {
    files = [...files]
    files.forEach(previewFile)
}

function previewFile(file) {
    let reader = new FileReader()

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = function() {
        let img = document.createElement('img');
        let div = document.createElement('div');

        img.src = reader.result;
        div.appendChild(img);

        document.getElementById('gallery').appendChild(div);
    }
}

dropArea.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false)
```

Comment: `readAsDataURL` waaaaay more expensive than `createObjectURL`.

Comment: What is `file`, exactly? Is it *already* a Base64-encoded file, or a binary file?

Comment: You need to use the `load` event of the `HTMLImageElement`, not the `FileReader`.

Comment: Try changing to just "load" event instead of 'onloadend'. 
Get into these possible duplicated suggestions:
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/26934286

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6150397

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS - get image width and height from the base64 code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17774928/js-get-image-width-and-height-from-the-base64-code)

Comment: file is the drag image.. its a drag n drop implementation

Comment: Actually the code snippets are already working. i just need height out that

Comment: the given link was visited by me before i asked. when i tried. in my case it just return 0

Comment: I updated the question with full code.. so that you may have clear view what I am trying to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Where-possible you should use `createObjectURL` instead of using `data:`-URIs in scripts because a `data:`-URI requires serializing the entire object into memory as a string with 1/3rd extra memory usage (so if you have a 1MB-sized image, you now need **an additional 1.33MB** just for the `data:` URI string, whereas an object URL is usually just a short GUID).

  - Creating data URIs is also synchronous and blocks the UI thread - you can easily freeze a Chrome tab  by creating a `data:` URI from a large image or video.
  - Whereas `createObjectURL` is very, very cheap - the only catch is you need to watch the lifetime of the URL and make sure you use `revokeObjectURL`.

Change your code to this.

Note that `FileReader` is not needed at all.

```
async function printImageDimensions( file ) {
    
    if( !file ) return;
    if( !( file instanceof File ) ) return;

    //

    const img = document.createElement( 'img' );
    
    const objUrl = URL.createObjectURL( file );
    try {
        
        const dim = await loadImageAsync( img, objUrl );

        console.log( "Width: %d, Height: %d", dim.w, dim.h );
    }
    finally {
        URL.revokeObjectURL( objUrl );
    }
}

function loadImageAsync( img, url ) {
    
    return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
        
        function onLoad() {
            const ret = { w: img.naturalWidth, h: img.naturalHeight };
            resolve( ret );
        }

        function onError() {
            reject( "Load failed." );
        }

        img.addEventListener( 'load', onLoad );
        img.addEventListener( 'error', onError );

        img.src = url;
        
    } );
}
```

Comment: Tried `reader.createObjectURL(file);` i got error saying not a function

Comment: I updated the question with full code.. so that you may have clear view what I am trying to do

Comment: @Fil It's `URL.createObjectURL`, not `reader.createObjectURL`, and as I said, you don't need `FileReader` at all.

Comment: Yeah it works.. sorry i did not follow properly