# Resize and preview base64 image, javascript

Tags: javascript

i am a newbie to programming,

I have an HTML code for displaying base64 image the image is dynamic link, always come with different sizes

I need to resize that image and create preview mode with smaller image with an aspect ratio
ex:
my original image on html are 600x300 I need to preview it 300x150
my original image HTML are 1000x500 I need to preview 500x250

I have a javascript for resizing but can't figure out how to get image base64 from my HTML code

Please who can give me some help on these to archive my goal

I cant paste HTMl code here because is to long please check HTMl on codepin

https://codepen.io/Gilavani/pen/JjLXBOb

```
function resizedataURL(datas, wantedWidth, wantedHeight)
{
    // We create an image to receive the Data URI
    var img = document.createElement('img');

    // When the event "onload" is triggered we can resize the image.
    img.onload = function()
        {        
            // We create a canvas and get its context.
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

            // We set the dimensions at the wanted size.
            canvas.width = wantedWidth;
            canvas.height = wantedHeight;

            // We resize the image with the canvas method drawImage();
            ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, wantedWidth, wantedHeight);

            var dataURI = canvas.toDataURL();

            /////////////////////////////////////////
            // Use and treat your Data URI here !! //
            /////////////////////////////////////////
        };

    // We put the Data URI in the image's src attribute
    img.src = datas;
}
```

Thanks you in Advice
Best Regards

Comment: Show us your HTML of image.

Comment: Hello @ChangAlex please here is the code please could you check on codepin : https://codepen.io/Gilavani/pen/JjLXBOb

Answer (score 0):

```js
    let srcImg = document.getElementById("orignal").src;
    let prev = document.getElementById("preview");
    function resizedataURL(datas, wantedWidth, wantedHeight)
    {
        prev.src = datas;
        prev.onload = function()
        {
          var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
          var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
          canvas.width = wantedWidth;
          canvas.height = wantedHeight;
          ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, wantedWidth, wantedHeight);
          prev.src = canvas.toDataURL();
        };
    }
    resizedataURL(srcImg, 150,150);
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <img id="orignal" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
    <h2>Preview</h2>
    <img id="preview" src="#">
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality. Without sufficient explanation, your answer is hard to understand.
If the OP can't understand your answer, then he also won't be able to reproduce your possible solution. As such it 
would be worthless to him/her or any further readers. Please add a sufficient explanation of your possible solution.

Comment: Hello @Ryヅ thanks you for your answear, i may not explain well my topic, please image base64 are dynamic and always come with different size, its possible to check the size and return the smaller preview with aspect ratio ??

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17774928/js-get-image-width-and-height-from-the-base64-code)check this